# Cloudfront not able access S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to use Signed URL for images and once I was able to do it. But then, I deleted it and trying to do it once again and I am not able to do it.

Here is what I have done so far:

1. Created a Cloudfront Key Pair in IAM Management Console. Downloaded
   the private and public key and also noted the Access Key ID =
   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.
2. Created a S3 bucket. No custom configuration
3. Created a Cloudfront distribution with the following settings

   - Origin domain name: my bucket
   - Restrict bucket access: Yes
   - Created a new Origin Access Identity
   - Grant read permissions on Bucket: Selected Yes
   - Restrict Viewer Access (Use Signed URLs or Signed Cookies) = Yes
   - Trusted Signers = Self

And then inside my laravel code, I have the following inside my controller:

```
$keyPairId = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';      
$privateKey = config_path('pk-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.pem');
$url = "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/image.jpg";
$cf = new UrlSigner($keyPairId, $privateKey);
$imgSrc = $cf->getSignedUrl($url, time());
echo "<img src='{$imgSrc}' />";
```

But every time I am getting the same error:

```
<Error>
<Code>MissingKey</Code>
<Message>Missing Key-Pair-Id query parameter or cookie value</Message>
</Error>
```

Need help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use CloudFront specific key pairs and add those to `$cf`.  More information on how to download or upload your own public key:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSecurityCredentials/1.0/AboutAWSCredentials.html#KeyPairs

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-trusted-signers.html#private-content-creating-cloudfront-key-pairs

Comment: I checked that. I have done that. Still not able to get it through.